# Not able to run test using --url

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

On running test using CLI by providing "--url" getting "error: unknown option '--url=https://www.google.com/'"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytbb8.png)

node version: 14.16.1
npm version: 7.10.0
testcafe version: 1.15.1

Answer (score 1):

[This issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6426) is fixed in the latest release candidate version (`npm i testcafe@v1.15.2-rc.1`).

**UPDATE**:
**The `1.15.2` version is now available. Please update your project.**